# trivial linear recurrence question

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

Note that: $\displaystyle\sum_{N \geq0}z^N = \frac{1}{1 - z}$

To solve the recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1} + 1$ for $n\geq1$ with $a_0 = 0$ we first multiply by $z^n$ and sum to get $\displaystyle\sum_{N \geq1}a_nz^N = \displaystyle\sum_{N \geq1}a_{n-1}z^n + \frac{z}{1-z}$. Would someone please show how the left-hand side $\displaystyle\sum_{N \geq1}a_nz^N$ becomes equal to the right-hand side $\displaystyle\sum_{N \geq1}a_{n-1}z^n + \frac{z}{1-z}$?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $z^n$ we obtain $$a_{n}z^{n}=a_{n-1}z^{n}+z^{n}$$

and summing gives $$\sum_{N\geq1}a_{N}z^{N}=\sum_{N\geq 1}a_{N-1}z^{N}+\sum_{N\geq 1}z^{N}$$
$$\sum_{N\geq1}a_{N}z^{N}=\sum_{N\geq 1}a_{N-1}z^{N}+\sum_{N\geq 0}z^{N+1}$$
$$\sum_{N\geq1}a_{N}z^{N}=\sum_{N\geq 1}a_{N-1}z^{N}+z\sum_{N\geq 0}z^{N}$$
$$\sum_{N\geq1}a_{N}z^{N}=\sum_{N\geq 1}a_{N-1}z^{N}+\frac{z}{1-z}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\sum_{N\ge 1} a_{N-1}z^N + \frac z{1-z} &= \sum_{N\ge 1} a_{N-1}z^N + z\sum_{N\ge0}z^N \\&= \sum_{N\ge 1} a_{N-1}z^N + \sum_{N\ge0}z^{N+1} \\&=\sum_{N\ge 1} a_{n-1}z^N + \sum_{N\ge1}z^N\\&=\sum_{N\ge 1} (a_{N-1}+1)z^N\\&=\sum_{N\ge 1} (a_N)z^N \end{align}$$